# Is 720p the max resolution in 3D mode in Gran Turismo 6

Tags: gran-turismo-6

Just downloaded the latest patch for GT6, to see that the game now supports 3D. However, when I select 3D mode, my nice and crisp 1080p is degraded to a quite grainy 720p, and I can't find a way to increase the resolution.

(My Philips 42" TV has passive 3D, and only every second scanline seems displayed in 3D mode, making the effective vertical resolution something like 360p, which is quite frankly disappointing, and nothing near the great image quality I get in 1080p).

Is 720p really the max resolution for GT6 in 3D? I can't find any online resources with definitive information on this.

Comment: Have you looked on the game's site? or creator's site? I mean if there is no solution online I doubt we can help you on here.

Comment: Using your math, in passive 3D, you would be comparing 360 to 540, not 1080. So take heart!

Comment: @horatio: Fair enough. Now, if I only knew how 540 would look, maybe I'd be happy with that.. ;-)